# How to get device orientation

Tags: android, c++, iphone, cocos2d-x

What is the best way to get the device orientation with cocos2d-x (c++)?

My Android/iOS application does support all 4 device orientations, and more important than knowing if it is landscape or portrait, I would like to know if it is upside down or not.

I will have to know from within a CCLayer.

**UPDATE**

I am trying to get events for right tilt and left tilt. To do so, I am calculating the angle at which the device is held. However, I need to know what orientation the device has, to be able to know if I am actually tilting left or right.

Comment: isnt being upside down the same as being right-side up? devices are a rectangle after all. Your perception of upside down might not be another persons

Comment: @tyczj Not for the Accelerometer

Comment: you might want to add that to your question then to explain what your problem is that you are trying to overcome

Comment: @tyczj Everyone should have the same perception of upside down considering there is definitely the bottom of a phone and the top of a phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though cocos2d-x is cross platform, few things are still very much platform dependent, for example, if you see the CCFileUtils, we have separate implementation files for iOS, Android etc, the cross platform is maintained with a single header,

Keeping that in mind,

In Android, you can get the device orientation by using the constants,

```
Surface.ROTATION_0 (no rotation)
Surface.ROTATION_90
Surface.ROTATION_180
Surface.ROTATION_270.
```

which you can get by calling `Display.getRotation()`
(It only rotate in all these directions if, `android:screenOrientation:fullSensor` is set)

And in iOS,
You can get the values with

```
UIDeviceOrientationPortrait
UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft
UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight
```

(It only rotates in all these directions if, `supportedInterfaceOrientations` method returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`)

Note:
Its not a good practice to rotate a phone upside down in portrait mode, only on tablets its accepted.. (Apple might even reject your app for this reason)

Let me know if you want to know how to use it, but googling the keywords will give you the usage..

Comment: Thanks, however "Its not a good practice to rotate a phone upside down in portrait mode" is not true and completely opinion based. Usually, when a user is using an app while connecting the device to a power source, he will want to use the app upside down because of the cable.

Answer (score 1):

After a quick google search :

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Device_Orientation

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/36414

**UDPDATE:**

I don't think you can determine the orientation the way you want to from cocos2d-x.
Then the only solution that I'm thinking of is to go into java through jni and use android's methods to determine the current orientation. Here's a 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12637954/how-to-detect-upside-down-orientation-in-android)
on how to determine all 4 orientations.

As for how to call java methods from c++, that's another ball game.

Comment: The first link is for setting the device orientation, the second one only can decide wether it is in landscape or portrait (in a rather ugly way) (it is the reason I wrote "more important than knowing if it is landscape or portrait, I would like to know if it is upside down or not")

Comment: If my answer pointed you to the right direction, please consider accepting it as the valid answer. thx.

Comment: Sorry, but the answer makes no sense. I am developing cross-plattform.